# What is the differenece between Vector and Vector<>

Tags: java, vector

i see some examples in java where vectors are declared as

```
Vector v = new Vector()
```

and in some examples,

```
Vector<String> = new Vector<String>()
```

i am not sure what does the latter declaration do? does it specify the type of Objects the Vector shud consist of?

if yes, then if i declare a Vector using the first declaration i can use any type of Objects and if i use the second declaration, then the object can only be of type within <>?

Comment: What programming language? It's really important to tag your questions with as much relevant information as possible. The language in question should almost always be the first tag. Also, backticks (`) allow you to highlight code as code, which is easier to read.

Comment: sorry, my bad....the language is java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line defines a `Vector` of `Object`s that can be of any type.

The second line uses [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) und define a `Vector` that only holds `String`s.

Answer (score 4):

This is a feature to Java called Generics.  You can find an Oracle-official resource [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

```
Vector v = new Vector();
```

is the same as

```
Vector<Object> v = new Vector<Object>()
```

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have answered, you're indeed dealing with a "Generic" class.

I'd recommend against using the Vector clsas, as it is deprecated. Instead, use  [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

A nice advantage of using Generics is that the compiler will provide you what is called "Type Safety".  When you initially declare your ArrayList as `ArrayList<Ball>`, the compiler will only let you store objects of class `Ball` (or its subclasses) in that list. Additionally, whenever you select an object from the list, i.e. `myList.get(index)`, the object returned from that call is automatically casted to a `Ball`.

Writing Generic classes can be tricky, but using them allows you to really clean up your code.

Here's a link to the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) on generics if you'd like more information.

Comment: i was looking at vectors because it was a chapter in the java book i was reading....but for sake of knowledge, what is adv of using ArrayList over Vectors? i know that  Vectors are preferred over ArrayList in multi-threaded scenarios!!